Flink backpressure when stream is split
If a stream split into two A and B using side output.
If A written directly to sink whereas B needs additional processing involving db call in a flatmap before persisting/publishing it to the same sink
Will backpressure in flatmap of stream B cause backpressure on the whole stream or will stream A be processed without getting affected?
